# The helper method added to TScrollBox does not work

Tags: delphi-2010

In one old project, which I was instructed to develop, there is a field of type TScrollBox.

```
FScroll   : TScrollBox;
```

To be able to handle the events of navigation buttons, the class must contain a WM_GETDLGCODE message handler. So I created a new class:

```
TScrollBoxArrowBtn = class(TScrollBox)
protected
  procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
end;
```

Implementation

```
procedure TScrollBoxArrowBtn.WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode);
begin
  Message.Result := DLGC_WANTARROWS;
end;
```

And replaced the TScrollBox type with TScrollBoxArrowBtn.

```
FScroll   : TScrollBoxArrowBtn;
```

The component began to respond to pressing the arrow button. But the copy, delete, SelectAll methods stopped working. This happened because the previous developer added to the verification methods like this:

```
"VariableName".ClassType = TScrollBox
```

I replaced them for verification:

```
"VariableName" is TScrollBox
```

After this methods of editing began to work. But I'm not sure that such a test will not be applied elsewhere in the project. So I decided to leave

```
FScroll   : TScrollBox;
```

And made TScrollBoxArrowBtn an helper class:

```
TScrollBoxArrowBtn = class helper for TScrollBox
protected
  procedure WMGetDlgCode(var Message: TWMGetDlgCode); message WM_GETDLGCODE;
end;
```

Unfortunately this method does not work. Verifications like `"VariableName".ClassType = TScrollBox` began to work perfectly, but project stopped responding to events arrow button. What did I do wrong?

I'm convinced that my version of IDE supports helper methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not find the answer specifically about the message methods in the helpers classes, but I found a way to solve my problem. In addition, I learned about many other bad features of the helper class, which finally convinced me to abandon their use. So my answer is - do not use the class helpers. At this time this is a very unstable tool. Perhaps in the future it will be improved.

Now about my decision. As I feared, the problem of checking the type of the following kind:

```
"VariableName".ClassType = TScrollBox
```

again appeared when merging the previously created branches. So I decided to replace the TScrollBox window procedure. I added field in the TScrollBox-field container class and I added a new window procedure for TScrollBox-field in the container class:

```
TCADParamsGroupBlockBaseScheme = class (TCADGroupBlockParams)
.....................................................
protected

  Old_FScroll_WindowProc   : TWndMethod;
  procedure New_FScroll_WindowProc(var Message: TMessage);
.....................................................
end;

implementation

procedure TCADParamsGroupBlockBaseScheme.New_FScroll_WindowProc(var Message: 
TMessage);
begin
  //Для обработки событий нажатий Key_Up/Down/Left/Right в DoKeyDown
  if Message.Msg = WM_GETDLGCODE then
    Message.Result := DLGC_WANTARROWS
  else Old_FScroll_WindowProc(Message);
end;
```

And in the constructor of the container class, I saved the pointer to the old TScrollBox-field window procedure and assigned it a new window procedure:

```
constructor TCADParamsGroupBlockBaseScheme.Create(const AOwner: TWinControl);
begin
...........................................
FScroll := TScrollBox.Create(FHost.Owner);

Old_FScroll_WindowProc := FScroll.WindowProc;
FScroll.WindowProc := New_FScroll_WindowProc;
............................................
end;
```